# Differentiation under the integral sign and change of variables

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f \in C^2 \left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ with a bounded support, and let  $f_\phi (x,y)=f(x\cos{\phi}-y\sin{\phi},x\cos{\phi}+y\sin{\phi}))$.

Show that:
$$\frac{d}{d\phi}\iint_{\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)}f_\phi(x,y) dxdy=-\int_\mathbb{R} f_\phi(x,0)xdx.$$

I think it has something to do with the fact that:
$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi }+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y }-x \frac{\partial}{\partial x }\right)f_\phi (x,y)=0$ and then change the variables somehow.

Any ideas?